# Payed off a vehicle and my ex has posession yet never payed me to sign off on title what can i do

Tags: car

Paid off a 2003 gmc Yukon in july, low and behold a month later my girlfriend of 2 1/2 years leaves me for another woman. took the vehicle that I have invested approximately 10,000$ between repairs and payments. I made the mistake of putting her name on the title. I have asked repeatedly for 3500$ and I would sign off on the vehicle. no attempt has been made to pay me for anything. always excuse after excuse. would it be wise to take to small claims to obtain the vehicle that I paid for that she has possession of?? the total cost of the vehicle was 7600$ then I put approximately 3000$ into repairs all over the vehicle to keep it in good running condidition with proof of repairs done out of a shop. will not pay insurance or license plate tags and is letting her now Wife drive the vehicle that she is uninsured on. I am still paying insurance on the vehicle cause I do not want anything to happen to me if the vehicle is wrecked. but with her wife driving the vehicle illegally how can I get the vehicle back. knowing I will never see the 3500$ wether or not I take her to court. need to know what options I have in this matter. local police will not help me. can I have it towed to my house and disable it til I see some money??? what can I do. theres no getting along anymore yet its all excuses and saying its her vehicle. yet I am listed first on the title and I have made 95% of the payments through a buy here pay here dealer with proof of payment. she had no legitimate job to pay for the vehicle so there is no income from her that proves she made any payments on the vehicle. PLEASE HELP!!!!

Comment: Sounds like you should consult a lawyer rather than a site about personal finance.

Comment: Whether she made any payments is irrelevant. If her name is on the title, she is (one of) the owner(s) of the vehicle. If she authorized someone to drive it, that person is not driving it illegally. If the two of you can't resolve the matter peaceably, you are stuck with working through the courts.

Comment: How are the names listed on the title? Is there an AND or an OR between your names?

Answer (score 1):

You are not perfectly clear, but I will assume that your ex-girlfriend owns the car and that her name is the only one on the title.

The fact that you paid off the loan and repaired the car is completely irrelevant. From a court's point of view you gifted the car to your girlfriend.

If you are listed on the title, then your best move is to steal the car and hide it so she can't steal it back. Note that you are not actually stealing it if you are listed on the title since you own the car. (Try to steal it when it is parked in some public place. Avoid going onto her property.) Wait until she gets hungry, then offer her $500 if she agrees to remove her name from the title.

By the way, after you steal the car, send a certified letter to her informing her that you have possession of the car. This is so that she has no grounds to report it stolen. Check with the police periodically to make sure she doesn't report it stolen anyway. If she reports it stolen AFTER you have notified her that you have possession, then it is a crime (making a false report).